# Looking for 70's movie title -- Secret agent with camera in glass eye

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to find a movie from the mid to late 1970's.  The scene that is stuck in my brain goes something like this:

A man walks into a very high security vault.  One of the security systems was a full body 'x-ray' (very much like the body-scanners today).  The man was not allowed to carry his watch, wallet or even a fountain pen that the xray showed on a blue screen.  His head didn't get xrayed because the machine only went up to his neck (this is an important plot point).

Once in the vault, he finds a file in a drawer and reads the papers in the file.  While he is doing this he taps his temple seeming to be concentrating.  He finishes, put the folder back in it's filing cabinet, and walks out.  On the way he retrieves his personal items, and thanks the guard.

Once he gets home (i think), he goes to a closet, and opens up a secret room.  The room is clearly a small photographic darkroom.  He pops out his eye on the side where he was tapping his temple.  He pulls it apart and reveals that it is a tiny-film camera.  He attaches it to some kind of spinning wand, and proceeds to dip in it several liquid filled trays.

Then he attaches the eye-camera to a projector, and we see the papers he was reading earlier.  I think they were in negative.  The papers had diagrams and stuff on them.  I think they were related to some kind of space program.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: i'm not entirely sure this is a duplicate, because the other question was asking about a completely difference scene in the movie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing you're thinking of "[Doppelgänger](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064519/)" AKA "Journey to the Far Side of the Sun":

And this scene...

...in particular.

Comment: Great find. How did we exist before YouTube?

Comment: Wow! somehow my brain separated it from Doppelganger...Thank you very much!

Comment: Woah! I have always remembered seeing this scene as a kid, but I could never remember where it was from. Thanks!

Comment: The movie is the same, but the question is completely different, so I don't consider this a duplicate at all.

Comment: @Alaska According to [our policy on dupe-closing story ID questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7065/31394), it *is* a duplicate.

Comment: It's almost a year later, I do not care at this point.